# Ignore property in nested object of the same type with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have one class which is entity and use the same class as a property:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
      private String name;
      @OneToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "supervisor_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
      private Employee supervisor;
      //getters and setters
}
```

I want to get the supervisor of an employee, but not the supervisor of the supervisor. Can I manage this somehow?

```
{
   "name": "PersonName",
   "supervisor": {
       "name": "Supervisor name",
       "supervisor": null // i don't want this one
   }
}
```

Comment: Use a DTO so you can define what you want and don't want.

Comment: You want "supervisor" property to be excluded in JSON ? Or in Entity?

Comment: In the end I made with nested classes, however I duplicated the attributes. At least it's clean and simple.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just used nested classes for both - dto and entity with fields needed.
True that I duplicated properties of the classes, but at least it's clean and simple.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore the nulls in the Json. The following works for me:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "supervisor_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Employee supervisor;
}
```

Here's the test

```
@Test
public void test2() throws Exception {
    Employee employee = makeEmployee("employee 1");
    Employee supervisor1 = makeEmployee("supervisor 1");
    employee.setSupervisor(supervisor1);

    Employee save = employeeRepository.save(employee);

    System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(save));
}
```

Here's my test output:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "employee 1",
  "supervisor" : {
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "supervisor 1"
  }
}
```

Make sure you use the correct JsonSerialize **org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize** not com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize